# Optimal Server / Database architecture for dual web / mobile app

Tags: ios, json, node.js, mongodb, server

I've been looking for awhile for a clear guide on how to set this up, and haven't really found a consensus.

Basically I want to build a simple data exchange app that runs on both a web browser and has comfortable endpoints for iOS. I'm still a bit of a noob so please excuse me if this is really off topic, but I'd love some advice on how to set this up so its easy to iterate and scale later on.

Currently I'm running the actual server that handles data crunching on node.js, and I have mongoDB running to store several json files for each user and some other nodes defined as data feeds that the user can subscribe to. The json files for storage are set up as

```
{
    "feeddetails": {
        "title": "title",
        "datecreated": "datecreatedUNIX",
        "createdby": "username",
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
    }    }
```

as the data feed info, and then similarly

```
{
"userdetails": {
    "name": "name",
    "datecreated": "datecreatedUNIX",
    "createdby": "email",
    "life": "1.3254",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
} }
```

Then simply each user has a feed that's structured of links as

```
{
"content": [{
    "id": "id",
    "user": "user",
    "url": "url",
    "timesubmitted": "timesubmitted",
    "score": "score"
} }
```

and each datafeed has a similar one.

So thats all pretty straightforward, and I stored the content in a folder structure kind of similar to reddit with /f/feedname and /u/username as the accesspoints for each part. Then I just have another json that stores a hashed password and handles authorization with passport.js as shown [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/).

The front end is kind of the part I'm curious about. Right now obviously the mobile app side just uses post and get requests to exchange content with the endpoints noted above. I think I'm going to try to get better at rails and build a web solution that can just send requests to the localhost on the server to get information from the node.js server but I'm really curious what you guys think would be a good solution for that side.

Please let me know if there's any more detail that I can provide.
Also, shoutout to [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), which I found to be a fantastic tool in learning how to use GET / POST requests.

Thanks in advance.

Itchyspacesuit

Answer (score 0):

SO! Looks like no one had much to say about this. I went ahead and built it (example coming soon) and it seems to be working quite well so far.

Basically, I used the node.js app I built to create the rest endpoints for the iOS app, and then built a rails app on the same server as the node.js app that uses those endpoints to present a nice responsive web app.

This really was a simple and effective way to do this. It works nicely because my node.js app is running on port 3000, so I just set up the rails app on port 80 of the same server as a nice and easy web app with the same back end.

Hope this helps someone!